# Simultaneously update two textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox

When I insert data in textbox1, I need that in textbox2 is placed same data simultaneously.

I dont know which event permits this feature. Im using visual studio 2010.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the contrary have to happen as well (`textbox1` updated after `textbox2` is edited)? Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Im using Windows Forms. no, textbox2 is ReadOnly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TextChanged` event on `textbox1` and use it to update `textbox2`:

```
// This can be done via designer too.
this.textbox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textbox1_TextChanged);
```

Now, in your form class:

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this handler to the `TextChanged` event of `textBox1`:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox2.Text = textBox.Text;
}
```